# foreign key is not working in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

I am using two tables in my db called conference db one for `paper` and another for `upload_data`
with two primary keys `paperid`(Primary key in paper table) and `id`(primary key in upload_data)

id is referenced in paper table and i cannot connect..query is executed.all the attributes except id in paper table can be inserted.

[image: i will be add the scrren shots of the table:Table-Paper]
[image: Table-upload_data]

Comment: Please, provide the query, you are executing. Ideally we'd like to see SQLfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different name for ID in the second table. call the foreign keys something like fk_name. add a fk_name column on the second table.